# Convert matrix 3x3 to 1x27 with bool value

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume I have a matrix 3x3 which values are from 0 to 3

```
[[1,0,0],
 [0,3,0],
 [0,0,2]]
```

I need it to be converted into 1x27 matrix with 0 or 1 values, so if there value more than 1 it would be 1, otherwise zero

```
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 1. 0.]
```

So far I've tried next, but it's wrong:

```
def convert(Matr):
  empty = np.zeros(Matr.shape[0]*Matr.shape[0]**2)
    for i in range(Matr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(Matr.shape[1]):
            if Matr[i,j] != 0:
                empty[i][((j+1)* Matr[i,j])-1] = 1
```

Comment: How exactly should 9 values become 27?

Comment: For example [0][0] = 1 => [1, 0, 0] or [0][0] = 2 => [0, 1, 0]

Comment: Is it perhaps a 3×3×3 matrix? One way to do this is to reshape the array to flatten. And the to use `A > 1` to get the boolean array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
              [0, 3, 0],
              [0, 0, 2]])

encoding = np.vstack((np.zeros((1, 3)), np.eye(3)))
result = encoding[a.ravel()].flatten()

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 1. 0.]
```

The variable encoding is an array, where each row corresponds to a code, for instance:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

Once you create the encodings iterate over each of the rows with `encoding[a.ravel()]` fetching the encodings for each value.